# I am trying to calculate the change of Geometric mean, but they don't match

Tags: algebra-precalculus, average

I have Day 1 data and Year 1 Data, and I used R to separately calculate their geometric mean as `Gmean(low$day1)` and `Gmean(low$year1)`

and their change as $year\, 1 - day\, 1$: `Gmean(low$diff)`

but why `Gmean(low$year1) - Gmean(low$day1)` does not match with their changes in geometric mean `Gmean(low$diff)`?

Comment: Your question is hard to read.  Please use Mathjax to format your equations

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you only had two values of each, I would not think this might be true except in very special cases.

There is no reason to think $\sqrt{y_1 y_2} - \sqrt{d_1 d_2}$ should equal $\sqrt{(y_1-d_1) (y_2-d_2)}$.

It would be different with arithmetic means: $\frac{y_1+y_2}2 - \frac{d_1+d_2}2 = \frac{(y_1-d_1)+(y_2-d_2)}2$ because everything is nicely linear